# NotesSession.AddressBooks == null. Any ideas why?

Tags: c#, com, lotus-notes, lotus

After I initialized NotesSession with some user ID, session gets initialized but the property NotesSession.AddressBooks becomes NULL. It is only for certain user IDs, but I cannot find any reasons, what is wrong with those users.

```
NotesSession session = new NotesSession();
                session.Initialize(password);
if (session.AddressBooks != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "addressBooks Length: {0}", session.AddressBooks.Length));
                        foreach (IDatabase addressBook in session.AddressBooks)
                        {
                            if (addressBook.IsPublicAddressBook)
                            {
                                addressBookInfo.Add(addressBook.FilePath, addressBook.FileName);
                                Console.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "addressBook.FileName:{0}  ", addressBook.FileName));
                                Console.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "addressBook.FilePath:{0} ",  addressBook.FilePath));
                                Console.WriteLine();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "addressBook.IsPublicAddressBook: {0}", addressBook.IsPublicAddressBook));
                                Console.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "addressBook.FileName: {0}", addressBook.FileName));
                                Console.WriteLine();
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

}

Any ideas why it happens?
Any Idea please help

Comment: Post your code. We are not mind readers ?

Comment: Close as duplicate of this 10 year old question??  ;)  http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/869c7412fe5d56b7852569fa007826e3/76650cf7418415b985256efa00563dc1?OpenDocument

Comment: What else have you checked in order to prove that the session is valid?session.userName, session.effectiveUserName, session.serverName?

Comment: I am able to open the names.nsf database using this session.getdatabase method. and yes session.username and other value return values but session.addressbook is null. Please help

Comment: do not close as the link Ken Pespisa mentioned does not have a answer to my question.